# Configuração multi-telas Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio

Bom basicamente eu tenho 2 telas, uma tratada como primária pelo windows, e outra como secundária.

Ao compilar um código na tela secundária que é onde eu deixo o código a execução acontece na minha tela principal.

Eu sou novo na utilização de duas telas ou mais no workflow e gostaria de saber qual o jeito de modificar este comportamento(eu sei que deve ter, mas não consegui achar em fóruns ou na microsoft exatamente o que eu quero).

Por exemplo eu gostaria de configurar para que a execução ocorresse na própria segunda tela, ou posteriormente em uma terceira tela só para debug, e não que ela atrapalhasse o que estou fazendo na tela do meio por exemplo.

Existe algum jeito de fazer isso? (Pre-configurado, pois sei que Windows+shift+seta envia para a tela na direção escolhida).

Comment: Após longo tempo de procura, não encontrei a solução exata para o problema citado, o máximo que consigo pensar é uma "gambiarra", na situação citada de 3 telas, você faria uma das telas a sua tela principal nas configurações do windows, e apesar dela estar setada como a principal, você utilizaria as outras telas para trabalhar e etc.